# Particle の following topic marker?

Tags: grammar, particle-の

> 大切にされるタイプってのもあるんだね。
>   Type who is prized ?????

I can't figure out what the particle soup after タイプ means. I'm assuming that って is the colloquial topic marker. If so, then I'm really confused about what の is doing.

I'm guessing that the overall meaning is "There are also types (of people) who are prized, aren't there?". But I can't break down the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the って you are seeing here is the colloquial form of という。 The　の is just the vague noun placeholder. If you look at it that way, it makes a lot more sense:

> 大切にされるタイプというの - Cherished(by someone) type(type thing)
>
> もあるんだ - Also exists

Hard to tell without context but it probably means something like "Cherished types also exist"

For clarification, you can replace の with もの：

> 大切にされるタイプというもの - The type that is cherished

Comment: Thanks. という drives me mad. In this case what nuance is added that is different from 大切にされるタイプもあるんだね?

Comment: @user3856370  There's a lot of possible ways to interpret the sentence, but try to understand it literally to capture a bit of the nuance. In your example, the clause is defined by という so you get something similar to "A cherished type of thing also exists" kind of nuance. The ね as a sentence ending there really emphasizes this nuance, so it becomes "A cherished type of thing also exists, doesn't it" with an agreeing tone(not questioning tone) - the type of tone in a sentence like "[laughing] it really is that way, isn't it". It confirms something while emphasizing what's confirmed(the [という]もの)